# How to schedule c# script to run on AWS?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cron

Actually I have did some research to run CRON job on AWS but did not found any good document which explain how to run c# script in AWS periodically.

I have found that we could do it with CloudWatch + Lambda, but it will not help in my case because Lambda has maximum 5 min timeout.

Then I start more research on this and found that there is a 'AWS Elastic Beanstalk' which has two options to select environment:

```
Web server environment
Worker environment
```

[image]

But here we can't create a script for .NET C# for worker environment.
So what are another options to create cron jobs on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I do this by creating a self-hosted c#/.net webapi as a windows service running on my ec2 instance.

The main loop of this webapi/windows service polls a dedicated SQS queue for 'jobs' to complete.

I then use aws cloudwatch events to put those jobs into the SQS queue at the desired interval. i.e. every hour, every day, every 5 minutes etc.

Its not as easy as just pasting a c# script someplace and telling it when to run, but it does give you a nice flexible framework for hanging lots of custom jobs that take a long time to run, and need to run on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks @E.J. Brennan, It's help a lot.
But Is it possible that if I will create a window service only and then it will polls a dedicated SQS queue?
It would be great if you have a link of any tutorial which explain about it.